# Why pressure is not same at the same horizontal level for different fluids?

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics

Imagine a manometer if one end is filled with **fluid A** and other with **fluid B** then why pressure at same level is not same?

Comment: Hint: Think in terms of a free body diagram.

Comment: Why do you expect being the same?

Comment: @Physiker if we consider the given manometer which has two different fluid and consider two points which are at same level and in same fluid but one of it has another fluid above it then why this time pressure is same

Answer (score -2):

Pressure is the derivative of energy with respect to volume. I.e. it's the ratio of how much energy it would take to increase the volume by some infinitesimal amount, divided by that infinitesimal amount, $\frac{\Delta E}{\Delta V}$. If you have a more dense fluid, then it will take more energy to push it out of the way, so pressure will be higher.